# How to rewrite ElasticSearch DSL query with the Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got a working query for ElasticSearch, but I have problems to execute the same query with the Java API of ElasticSearch.

How can I express the query below with the Java API of ElasticSearch?

```yaml
---
size: 0

query:
  match_all: []

facets:
  age:
    statistical:
      field : timestamp
```

Comment: Can you post the exact problem that you are getting. Might be better if you post the Java API version of your attempted query. Here the documentation of [Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like:

```java
client.prepareSearch("yourindex")
      .setTypes("yourtype")
      .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
      .addFacet(FacetBuilders.statisticalFacet("age").field("timestamp"))
      .setSize(0)
      .execute()
      .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your query DSL to a JSON string, and then wrap it with `QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery()` or `WrapperQueryBuilder()`, finally do the query with Java API like this.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("yourIndex")
                                .setTypes("yourType")
                                .setQuery(dslQB)
                                .setFrom(currentItem)
                                .setSize(pageSize)
                                .execute()
                                .actionGet();
```

`